# Blank page when using puppeteer on wordpress site

Tags: python, puppeteer

I am getting a blank page when I am trying to get this page. It's working for other WordPress websites though. I tried different option but none works.

```
import asyncio
import pyppeteer
import os
async def main():
    print("in main")
    browser = await pyppeteer.launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://mindcet.org/')
    await page.screenshot({'path': 'mindcet.png'})
    # await browser.close()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: You should probably wait for page to finish loading. Adding `await page.waitForNavigation({'waitUntil': 'networkidle2'})` after the `goto` might do the trick.

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

Using [the puppeteer stealth plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) I was able to solve the problem.